# SAPUI5 refresh binding / model after path has changed

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to update the content of a `Sap.m.List` control. It keeps holding the same Model, but the binding path for that model changes.

Is there any function which I could use to update my Sap.m.List to display the data inside a new binding path?
I tried using `oList.getModel().setPath()` and after that a refresh of the model, but this did not change the content of the list.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the binding context, you can get a new context via the path

```
var oModel = oList.getBindingContext().getModel();
var oContext = oModel.getContext(sPath);
oList.setBindingContext(oContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Element bound to as follows:

```
var sPath = "<your new path>";
oList.bindElement(sPath);
```

if you need a handle to your list

```
var oList = this.getView().byId("<your-list-id>");
```

Hope this helps.